# Grand Child Category is displaying in all Child Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, multidimensional-array

Grand Child Categories are displaying in all Child categories not on their respective child categories.

I've tried looping the third level categories(Grand Child) but it is still displaying all grandchild to all child categories.

Here is the full code. Please do determine on what correct code to place on looping the grandchild category.

```
$html = '';

    $taxonomies = array( 
         'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'

    );
    $args = array(
        'number' => 8,
        'parent' => 0,
        'hide_empty' => FALSE,
        'exclude' => array( 16 )
    );


    $parent_product_categories = get_terms($taxonomies,$args);

     $html .= '<div class="sc-tab-wrapper">';   
        $html .= '<ul class="sc-tabs">';
            $datatab = 0;
            foreach($parent_product_categories as $parentprodcat) {
            $datatab++;
            $top_term_id = $parentprodcat->term_id;
            $top_term_name = $parentprodcat->name;
            $top_term_tax = $parentprodcat->taxonomy;

            $html .= '<li id="'.$top_term_id.'" class=" sc-tab-link '. ( ($datatab == 1) ?  "current"  :  '') .' " data-tab="tab-'.$datatab.'">'.$top_term_name.'</li>';


            $second_level_terms[] = get_terms( array(
                    'taxonomy' => $top_term_tax, // you could also use $taxonomy as defined in the first lines
                    'child_of' => $top_term_id,
                    'parent' => $top_term_id, // disable this line to see more child elements (child-child-child-terms)
                    'hide_empty' => false,
            ) );    

            } // end of top level foreach   
            $html .= '</ul>';


            if($second_level_terms) {   
                $contenttab = 0;    
                $html .= '<div class="sc-tab-content-wrapper">';    
                    foreach($second_level_terms as $row => $innerArray){
                        $contenttab++;
                        $html .= '<div id="tab-'.$contenttab.'" class="sc-tab-content '. ( ($contenttab == 1) ?  "current"  :  '') .' ">';

                            foreach($innerArray as $innerRow => $value){
                                $html .= '<ul>';
                                    $second_term_name = $value->name;
                                    $second_level_term_id = $value->term_id;
                                    $html .= '<li>'.$value->name;

                                    $third_level_terms[] = get_terms( array(
                                        'taxonomy' => $top_term_tax, // you could also use $taxonomy as defined in the first lines
                                        'parent' => $second_level_term_id,
                                        //'child_of' =>  $second_level_term_id,
                                        'hide_empty' => false,
                                    ) );

                                    if($third_level_terms) {
                                        foreach($third_level_terms as $third_level_row => $third_level_array){
                                            foreach($third_level_array as $third_level_key =>  $third_level_value){
                                                $html .= '<p>'.$third_level_value->name.'</p>';
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }

                                $html .= '</li>';       
                            $html .= '</ul>';
                            }

                        $html .= '</div>';
                    }
                $html .= '</div>';
            } // end of if second leve term 

            //echo '<pre style="padding-left:200px;">';
            var_dump($third_level_terms);
            //echo '</pre>';

    return $html;
```

Expected Results should be that GrandChild Categories should list on their respective Child Category and not display all Grandchild Categories to all Child Categories.

Comment: Probably you did from there. There is some usages underneath https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/259175/how-to-display-child-term-of-current-terms-parent-taxonomy

Answer (score 0):

Try 'depth' => 1 ,   // Only show one level of hierarchy

This will tell your query to only call one level.